# Permission Denied error with Get-ChildItem in PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, ffmpeg, permission-denied, get-childitem

Whenever I try to run my PowerShell script, I get an error. Please note that I don't have much programming knowledge.

Here is the code (with some folder names replaced)

```
cd -Path "F:\****\folder1"
$files = Get-ChildItem
foreach ($file in $files) {
  $newName = $file.BaseName + ".mp3"
  ffmpeg -i $file.FullName -codec:a libmp3lame -b:a 320k $newName
}
```

Inside of folder1, there is folder2, which has the files I want to get. I'm not running in folder2, because in the future there will be a folder3 inside of folder1 and I want to get files from both. I am getting the error:

```
F:\****\folder1\folder2: Permission denied
```

I believe the error is with `Get-ChildItem`. How can I fix this? I am running the script as administrator.

Comment: Do you have the appropriate permissions on those files and folders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question properly, you have a source folder `"F:\****\folder1` where files are kept inside subfolder(s) that need to be processed.

In order to do that you need to add the `-File` aswell as the `-Recurse` switch on the Get-ChildItem cmdlet.

Something like this:

```
$sourceFolder = "F:\Somewhere\folder1"
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceFolder -File -Recurse
foreach ($file in $files) {
    $newName = [System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($file.FullName, ".mp3")
    # since the output file should go into the same directory, you can do
    # $newName = [System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($file.Name, ".mp3")
    ffmpeg -i "$($file.FullName)" -codec:a libmp3lame -b:a 320k "$newName"
}
```

Of course you need to have permission to create new files inside the source folder and its subdirectories

Comment: I tried that, replacing the example folder with the actual folder. It loads the files and they show up, but then I get `At least one output file must be specified` in red at the bottom of each time it tries to process a file.

Comment: @owcs Perhaps the output file has spaces in the path. Try quoting it `"$newName"`. Since you convert to the original path anyway, you can also safely change `$newName = [System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($_.FullName, ".mp3")` into `$newName = [System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($_.BaseName, ".mp3")`. I have added that to the answer.

Comment: I'm still getting the error. This is what shows up for each song (still with names changed): https://pastebin.com/jnPkdgZX

Comment: @owcs Sorry, made a typo.. I meant to say `$newName = [System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($_.Name, ".mp3")`

Comment: hmm, I tried that and got the same exact result, both when using `$_.Name` and `$_.FullName`

Comment: @owcs Ah, stupid me.. I tested first using a ForEach-Obkect loop, later decided to do foreach($file..), but forgot to change the `$_` into `$file` when pasting the code. Fixed now. (because your exampe shows you have spaces in the inputpath, I've quoted that aswell, just to make sure)

Comment: Worked perfectly and put the files in the right place. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, `$files = Get-ChildItem` will get all items in `F:\****\folder1` which will also be the folder `folder2` which cannot be processed by `ffmpeg`. You can add the `-File` switch to exclude folders:

```bsh
$files = Get-ChildItem -File
```